# Using a different JVM for MATLAB on Windows

Tags: java, matlab, windows-10

I needed to access some java libraries in MATLAB, but the JVM is of an older version. I tried setting MATLAB_JAVA to the path of my current version `C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4` but I get a fatal error on startup:

> Unable to start JVM because of an invalid Java option.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?

Comment: I had tried and my solution is to remove Java 9 and install Java 8. It worked.

Comment: This was a year ago, and if I recalled correctly I ended up not using MATLAB for what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows+r, the type: sysdm.cpl
When this is opened click advanced and then go to environmetal settings.
Then there should be a line saying JAVA_OPTION, click it and delete it.